# Get runtime getter of interface property

Tags: c#, reflection

Declarations:

```
interface I
{
    int i { get; set; }
}

class C : I
{
    public int i { get; set; }
}
```

Code:

```
C c = new C();
c.i = 10;
PropertyInfo pi1 =
    c.
    GetType().
    GetInterfaces().
    SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties()).
    ToArray()[0];
PropertyInfo pi2 =
    c.
    GetType().
    GetProperties()[0];
object v1 = pi1.GetValue(c);
object v2 = pi2.GetValue(c);
```

Hey, `v1 == v2`, `pi1 != pi2`, but `GetValue` obviously calls same method. How can I know in my code that `pi1` and `pi2` call same method body?

Comment: Just a guess. Have you tried: `pi1.DeclaringType == pi2.DeclaringType && pi1.Name == pi2.Name`?

Comment: @itsme86 `DeclaringType` is different: `I` and `C`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Type.GetInterfaceMap()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getinterfacemap(v=vs.110).aspx) to get a mapping between interface members and the implementing members for a specific type. Here's an example:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

interface I
{
    int Value { get; set; }
}

class C : I
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var interfaceGetter = typeof(I).GetProperty("Value").GetMethod;
        var classGetter = typeof(C).GetProperty("Value").GetMethod;
        var interfaceMapping = typeof(C).GetInterfaceMap(typeof(I));

        var interfaceMethods = interfaceMapping.InterfaceMethods;
        var targetMethods = interfaceMapping.TargetMethods;
        for (int i = 0; i < interfaceMethods.Length; i++)
        {
            if (interfaceMethods[i] == interfaceGetter)
            {
                var targetMethod = targetMethods[i];
                Console.WriteLine($"Implementation is classGetter? {targetMethod == classGetter}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That prints `Implementation is classGetter? True` - but if you change the code so that fetching `I.Value` *doesn't* call `C.Value`, e.g. by adding a base class so that `C.Value` is a new property, not an implementation of `I.Value`:

```
interface I
{
    int Value { get; set; }
}

class Foo : I
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

class C : Foo
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

... then it will print `Implementation is classGetter? False`.